# How do I implement Harp GL in Blazor?

Tags: three.js, heremaps

I want to implement HereMap's harp GL 3D maps in my Blazor project. Because I would like to use specific node packages in my project how should I go about adding this? The HereMaps guide is not very specific on implementing Harp GL. Jumps from Just js files to then having typescript and node packages.

https://developer.here.com/tutorials/harpgl/#install-harp.gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, in your root project folder, create a JS folder. Then add an src folder.
Move your js files from your wwwroot/js/ into the JS/src folder.

Now install Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild NuGet package to your project. You will be using typescript.

Right-click your project, hit add>new and select TypeScript JSON configuration file. Do not change the name. Hit ok.

replace the contents in your newly created tsconfig.json file with the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Now right-click on your JS folder, and hit open in terminal.
Paste the following: `npm init -y`
Once that is done we will need to install Harp GL: `npm i @here/harp.gl`
For any additional packages, you will follow the same process, eg: `npm i @here/harp.gl`

Build your solution. If you followed this correctly it should build successfully.
You can now use the packages in your typescript files like so:

```
import { Style, StyleSet } from "@here/harp-datasource-protocol";
import { GeoCoordinates, sphereProjection } from "@here/harp-geoutils";
...
```

Any further questions, please comment below. I made the mistake of just installing `@here/harp-datasource-protocol` when I first would need to install `@here/harp.gl`. Writing this here for any other junior devs pulling their hair out over the Here documentation. Happy Coding!

Comment: Another thing I will add, is that the webpack output section must have library target and library set. e.g: 

libraryTarget: 'umd',
library: 'EntryPoint'